# What is the difference in using 'rises' and 'rising'?

Tags: meaning, differences

I get stuck about using a vert after an object. More specifically, can I use 'rises' instead of 'rising' in the following sentence:
*"There are 130 of them altogether, each one '**rising**' between 20 and 25 meters from the ground to support a frame of iron bars on which the roof originally rested*". If it's accepted, please anyone can help me explain the difference when using it. And what are the contexts we should use the verb + ing like about sentences? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As is so often the case with this sort of question it depends on the context. What you have provided is not sentence because it does not start with a capital letter so there must be more words, and probably punctuation, in front of it. Give us the entire sentence and we may be able to answer your question.

Comment: Hi BoldBen, I just adjusted my question

Comment: Thanks, I think we must have overlapped, the edit didn't show while I was making that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the *rising* version and the *rises* version is that the first is **untensed**  and the second is **tensed.** In other words, the first one can't stand as a complete sentence by itself, while the second can. The shortest English sentence **Go** is possible only because it is tensed (the subject of the sentence being implied in this case.)

**EDIT**

I can see that the OP has modified the question a good deal. Consequently, the answer needs to be modified as well. But since the logic is still the same as I've outlined earlier, I hope the OP is able to see for themselves why their changed version reads like a complete sentence.

Comment: Actually, I still get confused about it. Is it a reduced relative clause or other points?. Or we just need to remember that after a main sentence, we should use a verb + ing like that?

Comment: Follow the grammar point that you mentioned. I found it in the Cambridge dictionary. "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/clauses-finite-and-non-finite". Now I can get it, thanks so much for your help:)))))

Comment: @Myn13: Yes, you're on the right track. Glad my answer helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

"each one rising between 20 and 25 meters from the ground to support a frame of iron bars on which the roof originally rested" is **not** a sentence.  You cannot find the subject and verb.

"Each one rises between 20 and 25 meters from the ground to support a frame of iron bars on which the roof originally rested." is a sentence.

There are many pillars, each one rising between 20 and 25 meters from the ground to support a frame of iron bars on which the roof originally rested."  is a sentence.

---

**added**

> There are 130 of them altogether, each one rising between 20 and 25 meters from the ground to support a frame of iron bars on which the roof originally rested.

is a sentence.

With "rises" perhaps use a semicolon, since there are two separate clauses.

> There are 130 of them altogether; each one rises between 20 and 25 meters from the ground to support a frame of iron bars on which the roof originally rested.

Maybe better, two sentences.

> There are 130 of them altogether.  Each one rises between 20 and 25 meters from the ground to support a frame of iron bars on which the roof originally rested.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as you mentioned in the third sentence, why we use 'rising' instead of 'rises'. I'm wondering that is it a reduced relative clause?